# Mule 4 - Is there a recommended method of chunking a huge payload of say 3000 records in a JSON array into groups of 100 records

Tags: json, mulesoft

Our http POST call has a max size of 100, so we need split the 3000 into these small groups, call 100 each time and collect the returned payload until its exhausted all records.
 
Been attempting to use Batch aggregator and size based aggregator but both methods we try seem to 'lose' the payload and i either end up with the original 3000 records payload or just a collection of 100 TypedValues.
 
The payload we are passing into the aggregators looks like;

```
[
 2258571491,
 2258571831,
 2258571924,
 2258571953,
 2258572054,
 2258572339,
 2258572409,
 2258572653,
 2258572790,
 2258573009,
 2258573081
]
```

Even after reading the documentation religiously, i clearly have no idea what i'm doing..
Any recommendations?
 
Thanks!

Comment: Actually looks like i just had a corrupt element in my flow. Using the batch aggregator is working perfectly now. Just used basic payload throughout the batch job and looped as it should :)